# cakephp fetch in default layout not working

Tags: php, cakephp, layout, view, fetch

Hello i'm trying to fetch an element in my default layout but it's not displaying anything ive followed cakephp documentation about displaying blocks and i havent found my error.

My MenusController.php

```
<?php

class MenusController extends AppController{

    public function beforeFilter(){

        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow();

    }

    public function get_menu(){

      if ($this->Auth->user()['role'] == 'admin'){
        $this->set('dashboard_menu',$this->dashboard_menu_admin());
      }
      else
        $this->set('dashboard_menu',$this->dashboard_menu_user());

    }

    private function dashboard_menu_admin(){

        $dashBoardMenu = array(
                            array(
                                'elementName' => 'Usuarios',
                                'iconName'=> 'user',
                                'action' => 'users'
                               ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Personal',
                                  'iconName' => 'user',
                                  'action'=>'personal'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Resumen Semanal',
                                  'iconName' => 'edit',
                                  'action' => 'resumen'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Estadisticas',
                                  'iconName' => 'signal',
                                  'action' => '#'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Tareas',
                                  'iconName' => 'check',
                                  'action' => '#'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Calendario',
                                  'iconName' => 'calendar',
                                  'action' => '#'),
                            array('elementName' => 'Nube',
                                  'iconName' => 'cloud',
                                  'action'=> '#')
                   );

        return $dashBoardMenu;

    }

    private function dashboard_menu_user(){

        $dashBoardMenu = array(
                            array(
                                'elementName' => 'Usuarios',
                                'iconName'=> 'user',
                                'action' => 'users'
                               ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Resumen Semanal',
                                  'iconName' => 'edit',
                                  'action' => 'resumen'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Estadisticas',
                                  'iconName' => 'signal',
                                  'action' => '#'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Tareas',
                                  'iconName' => 'check',
                                  'action' => '#'
                                  ),
                            array('elementName' => 'Calendario',
                                  'iconName' => 'calendar',
                                  'action' => '#'),
                            array('elementName' => 'Nube',
                                  'iconName' => 'cloud',
                                  'action'=> '#')
                   );

        return $dashBoardMenu;

    }

}
```

In View/Menus/get_menu.ctp

```
<?php
$this->start('menu');
    echo $this->element('menu/dashboard_menu',array('menuItems' => $dashboard_menu));
$this->end();
```

?>

PART OF view/layouts/default.ctp

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="container">

        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            <?php if ($logged_in): ?>

              <?php  echo $this->fetch('menu'); //THiS IS NOT DISPLAYING ANYTHING  ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="span9" id="content">
                <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

I'm trying to print an echo "something" betwee start and end methods and ive got nothing.
i think its not fetching but i dont know why

Somebody can help me. thanks.

Comment: It appears you should go through the CakePHP tutorial first before trying to use content blocks.

Comment: Whatam i doing wrong?

Comment: What controller/action are you in?

Comment: MenuController.php and i got my get_menu method

Comment: Please take some time and make your question more detailed.  What is in your element (or what's being printed by it)?  What version of Cake are you using?  How does it work even though it should be MenusController (plural)?  ...etc. etc.

Comment: the way you are doing it will get the menu to be visible only when you access the this link [host]/menus/get_menu/ is that what you want or you want the menu to be displayed globally ?

Comment: i want to display menu globally

Comment: was anyone able to get this running?